# .wixproj file does not refresh properties during build

Tags: msbuild, wix, wix3

I've just implemented a new build script file to share code signing details among projects and allowing us to easily switch depending on if our main certificate is available or not. This is in our main application project as well as two WiX projects (msi and exe).

It seems like WiX remembers settings from the last build - for example, if I build with `cert.sign` in the correct place, then remove it and build again, it recalls the settings loaded from `cert.sign` during the first build rather than using `test.sign` as expected. This is not an issue in regular `.csproj` files.

The `.sign` file I've set up (one per certificate):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Certificate>test.pfx</Certificate>
    <FilePath>$(SolutionDir)</FilePath>
    <Pwd>cert_pwd</Pwd>
    <TimeStamp>/tr http://timestamp.server.com</TimeStamp>
    <AppName>My App</AppName>
    <Url>www.example.com</Url>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The main `.csproj` file (this works):

```
...
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)..\..\.cert\cert.sign" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)..\..\.cert\cert.sign')"/>
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\test.sign" Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)..\..\.cert\cert.sign')"/>
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>signtool sign /f $(FilePath)$(Certificate) /p $(Pwd) $(TimeStamp) /d $(AppName) /du $(Url) $(TargetPath)</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
...
```

One of the `.wixproj` files (this doesn't work):

```
...
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)..\..\.cert\cert.sign" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)..\..\.cert\cert.sign')"/>
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\test.sign" Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)..\..\.cert\cert.sign')"/>
<Target Name="SignMsi">
  <Exec Command="signtool sign /f $(FilePath)$(Certificate) /p $(Pwd) $(TimeStamp) /d $(AppName) /du $(Url) @(SignMsi)" />
</Target>
...
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Could it be an issue in the `SignMsi` and `SignExe` targets?  I'm on Visual Studio 2015 u2, WiX v3.10.2.2516

Comment: what doesn't work exactly? try running the build with increased verbosity [/v:detailed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

Comment: It seems like WiX remembers settings from the last build - for example, if I build with `cert.sign` in the correct place, then remove it and build again, it recalls the settings loaded from `cert.sign` during the first build rather than using `test.sign` as expected. This is not an issue in regular `.csproj` files.  (will update question shortly)

Comment: Hi Ben, have you found a solution? The bug is still not fixed in VS2015 u3, WiX 3.11

Comment: No solution yet as far as I'm aware.